# Does mysql have the fill function() when I use month() to fill data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the month() function to select the data,the sql and the result is :

`select month(loan_date)  mon,sum(loan_amount) total_loan from t_loan 
 group by mon;
 ---  mon   total_loan
 ---  6   1000
 ---  12   2000`

```
Now I want the result is:
---mon   total_loan
---1     0
--- 2    0
---3   0
--- 4  0
--- 5   0
---  6   1000
---  7   0
--- 8  0
--- 9   0
---  10   0
--- 11  0
---  12   2000`
```

Does mysql have the fill function() when I use month() to fill data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is just a simple 12 row union all subquery

```
SELECT
      mon.n, coalesce(total_loan,0) total_loan
FROM (
      select 1  n union all
      select 2  n union all
      select 3  n union all
      select 4  n union all
      select 5  n union all
      select 6  n union all
      select 7  n union all
      select 8  n union all
      select 9  n union all
      select 10 n union all
      select 11 n union all
      select 12
      ) mon
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            MONTH(loan_date) mon
          , SUM(loan_amount) total_loan
      FROM t_loan
      GROUP BY
            mon
      ) g ON g.mon = mon.n
```

Comment: Some databases do have "fill like" capabilities (e.g. "generate series" in Postgres or "recursive cte's" in several other dbs) but AFAIK not MySQL. [MySQL version 8 is expected to have cte's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html)